# How to find max average of values by converting list of tuples to dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to take average for all players with same name. I wrote following code. it's showing index error what's the issue?

Input: `l = [('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 122),
 ('Ashwin', 90)]`

Output: `l = [('Kohli', 40), ('Ashwin', 61.5), ('Pujara', 122)]`

```
t=0
l2=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if j < len(l) - 1 :
            if l[i][0] == l[j][0]:
                    l2[t][0] = l[j][0]
                    l2[t][1] = (l[j][1] + l[j+1][1]) / 2
                    t = t + 1
```

Comment: What are `t` and `l2`? All I can produce with what you've given are name errors.

Comment: t =0
l2 is empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with the help of default dict

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
l = [('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 122), ('Ashwin', 90)]

for k, v in l:
    data_dict[k].append(v)
data_dict = dict(data_dict)
# {'Pujara': [122], 'Ashwin': [33, 90], 'Kohli': [73, 7]}

for k,v in data_dict.items():
    data_dict[k] =  sum(v)/len(v)

# {'Ashwin': 61.5, 'Kohli': 40.0, 'Pujara': 122.0}
```

To convert the dict to list of tuples you can use zip i.e

```
list(zip(data_dict.keys(),data_dict.values()))

#[('Ashwin', 61.5), ('Pujara', 122.0), ('Kohli', 40.0)]
```

To find the maximum value you can use max  i.e

```
max(data_dict.values()) #122
```

To get the key you can use

```
[i for i,j in data_dict.items() if j == max(data_dict.values())] # ['Pujara']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your algorithm can work, because the average of `a`, `b` and `c` is `(a+b+c)/3`, not `((a+b)/2+c)/2`.

You could keep 2 [counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), one for occurences and one for scores:

```
l = [('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 122),
     ('Ashwin', 90)]

from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
scores = Counter()

for name, score in l:
  counts[name] += 1
  scores[name] += score

print(counts)
print(scores)
```

It outputs:

```
Counter({'Kohli': 2, 'Ashwin': 2, 'Pujara': 1})
Counter({'Ashwin': 123, 'Pujara': 122, 'Kohli': 80})
```

It shouldn't be too hard to iterate over `scores` and calculate averages now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using collections library

```
ip=[('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 122),
 ('Ashwin', 90)]

op=[]
players=set()

for item in ip:
    x,y=item
    players.add(x)

for player in players:
    sum_run=0
    ctr=0
    for i in ip:
        if player in i:
            x,y=i
            sum_run=sum_run+y
            ctr+=1
        else:
            pass

    avg_run=sum_run/ctr
    op_set = (player,avg_run)
    op.append(op_set)

print op
```

It outputs

```
[('Kohli', 40), ('Ashwin', 61), ('Pujara', 122)]
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `collections`? At a glance your code will be about `n ** 2`, it's longer, and less readable - see Zen of python.