# finding the maxaverage from given list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a Python function maxaverage(l) that takes a list of pairs of the form (name,score) as argument, where name is a string and score is an integer. Each pair is to be interpreted as the score of the named player. For instance, an input of the form [('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)] represents two scores of 73 and 7 for Kohli, two scores of 33 and 90 for Ashwin and one score of 122 for Pujara. Your function should compute the players who have the highest average score (average = total across all scores for that player divided by number of entries) and return the list of names of these players as a list, sorted in alphabetical order. If there is a single player, the list will contain a single name.

For instance, `maxaverage([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)])` should return ['Pujara'] because the average score of Kolhi is 40 (80 divided by 2), of Ashwin is 61.5 (123 divided by 2) and of Pujara is 122 (122 divided by 1), of which 122 is the highest.

In the same way the solution should be `['Kohli', 'Ashwin']` if `l = ([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara'‌​,22),('Ashwin',47)])` but I'm getting only kohli

```
from collections import defaultdict

def maxaverage(l):
    dl = []
    data_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in l:
        data_dict[k].append(v)
    data_dict = dict(data_dict)

    for k, v in data_dict.items():
        data_dict[k] = sum(v) / len(v)

    list(zip(data_dict.keys(), data_dict.values()))
    max(data_dict.values())
    x = (max(data_dict, key=data_dict.get))
    dl.append(x)
    return dl
```

Comment: Thats feels bit familiar code. And its not so clear of what your asking. Can you be more specific

Comment: It is stated in your question (and backed up by the input data) that Pujara should be the answer. And that is what your code will return. Why do you think that it should be Kohli and Ashwin?

Comment: `the solution should be Kohli and ashwin but getting only kohli` looks like you clearly haven't understood the problem statement. Go back and read it.

Comment: Test Case 2 
maxaverage([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',22),('Ashwin',47)])
solution should be-['Ashwin', 'Kohli'] but it only shows kohli

Comment: Its better you add test case 2 in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find max average of values by converting list of tuples to dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262664/how-to-find-max-average-of-values-by-converting-list-of-tuples-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes:

```
l = [('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 22), ('Ashwin', 47)]


def max_average(l):
    from operator import itemgetter
    from itertools import groupby
    lst_of_pairs = list()

    for key, group in groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0)):
        scores = list(x[1] for x in group)
        avg = sum(scores) / len(scores)
        lst_of_pairs.append((key, avg))

        lst_of_pairs.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    max_avg = lst_of_pairs[0][1]
    return list(e[0] for e in filter(lambda x: x[1] == max_avg, lst_of_pairs))


print(max_average(l))
```

And for the case in 'l', you can get ['Ashwin', 'Kohli'] as expected. Remeber that the groupby will only work on a sorted lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a list comprehension at the end of the method to get the keys of dict based on max average i.e

```
from collections import defaultdict

def maxaverage(l):
    data_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for k, v in l:
        data_dict[k].append(v)

    data_dict = dict(data_dict)

    for k, v in data_dict.items():
        data_dict[k] = sum(v) / len(v)

    dl = [i for i,j in data_dict.items() if j == max(data_dict.values())]
    return dl
```

Output:

```
maxaverage([('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 22), ('Ashwin', 47)])
#['Ashwin', 'Kohli']

maxaverage(([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)]) 
#['Pujara']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected version of your code that ensures that the final result is sorted alphabetically. It also has some efficiency improvements:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def maxaverage(l):
    data_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in l:
        data_dict[k].append(v)

    data_dict = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in data_dict.items()}

    max_avg = max(data_dict.values())
    return sorted([k for k in data_dict if data_dict[k] == max_avg])


>>> maxaverage(([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)]))
['Pujara']

>>> maxaverage([('Kohli', 73), ('Ashwin', 33), ('Kohli', 7), ('Pujara', 22), ('Ashwin', 47)])
['Ashwin', 'Kohli']
```

Note that the solution in the 2nd test case should be `['Ashwin', 'Kohli']`, not `['Kohli', 'Ashwin']` (as stated in your question) because the final list should be sorted.